# Gstreamer Missing plugins

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I am trying to run certain pipelines on the Command prompt for playing a video and I am often getting these errors/messages/warnings :

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "qtdemux"
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "playbin2"
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "decodebin2"
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "playbin".
```

***Following are the pipelines :***

```
gst-launch filesrc location=path to the mp4 file ! playbin2 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

or

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=path to the mp4 file ! qtdemux name=demuxer ! { queue ! decodebin ! sdlvideosink } { demuxer. ! queue ! decodebin ! alsasink }
```

or

```
gst-launch -v playbin uri=path to the mp4 file
```

or

```
gst-launch -v playbin2 uri=path to the mp4 file
```

## Questions

1. I wanted to know, if I am I missing the plugins to execute this.
2. How do I know which plugin is responsible for which or found where?
3. What is the benefit of implementing the pipeline via c code.Are the missing plugins still required.
4. Is it good to install the missing plugins form the Synaptic manager or form the [Gstreamer site(base,good,bad,ugly)](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/)
5. When we do `gst-inspect` we get output like this:

   ```
   postproc:  postproc_hdeblock: LibPostProc hdeblock filter
   libvisual:  libvisual_oinksie: libvisual oinksie plugin plugin v.0.1
   flump3dec:  flump3dec: Fluendo MP3 Decoder (liboil build)
   vorbis:  vorbistag: VorbisTag
   vorbis:  vorbisparse: VorbisParse
   vorbis:  vorbisdec: Vorbis audio decoder
   vorbis:  vorbisenc: Vorbis audio encoder
   coreindexers:  fileindex: A index that stores entries in file
   coreindexers:  memindex: A index that stores entries in memory
   amrnb:  amrnbenc: AMR-NB audio encoder
   amrnb:  amrnbdec: AMR-NB audio decoder
   audioresample:  audioresample: Audio resampler
   flv:  flvmux: FLV muxer
   flv:  flvdemux: FLV Demuxer
   ```

What does the x : y ( x and y mean ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Answers,

It looks like gstreamer at your ends was not installed correctly. playbin2, decodebin2 are basic and part of the base plugins

1 Yes you may be missing some plugins

2 Use gst-inspect command to check if it is available

3 From C code you can manage states, register callback, learn more
  Yes missing plugins are still required

4 I guess gstreamer site would be better

5 Not sure about this one, would help if you arrange the result in a proper way

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the GST_PLUGIN_PATH is incorrect. Please set the correct path to where the gstremer has been installed.

Answer (score 1):

the problem for me was that the path wasn't setup. Here is how to find the path:

`1. Locate Plugin Directories:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name '*gstreamer*1.0*'
```

you are looking for something like this:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
```

that it has all the .so files

then export and test:

```
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/path/to/gstreamer-1.0
gst-inspect-1.0 qtdemux
```

Disclaimer: the

```
sudo gst-inspect-1.0 qtdemux
```

was working even without setting up the path